# Example of a `Type 1` that is neither `Type` nor an inhabitant of `Type`

Tags: dependent-type, idris

What is an example of an inhabitant of `Type 1` that is neither `Type` nor an inhabitant of `Type`? I wasn't able to come up with anything while exploring in the Idris REPL.

To be more precise, I'm looking for some `x` other than `Type` that yields the following:

```
Idris> :t x
x : Type 1
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a type theory specialist, but here is my understanding. In the [Idris tutorial](http://eb.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/writings/idris-tutorial.pdf) there is a section **12.8 Cumulativity**. It says that there is an internal hierarchy of type universes:

```
Type : Type 1 : Type 2 : Type 3 : ...
```

And for any `x : Type n` implies `x : Type m` for any `m > n`. There is also an example demonstrating how it prevents possible cycles in the type inference.

But I think that this hierarchy is only for internal use and there is no possibility to create a value of `Type (n+1)` which is not in `Type n`.

See also articles in nLab about [universes in type theory](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/type+theory#universes) and about [type of types](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/type+of+types).

Maybe this [issue](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/408) in the idris-dev repository can be useful too. Edwin Brady refers there to the [Design and Implementation paper](http://eb.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/drafts/impldtp.pdf) (see section 3.2.2).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not an Idris expert, but I'd expect that

```
Type -> Type
```

is also in `Type 1`.

I'd also expect

```
Nat -> Type
```

and if you're very lucky (not so sure about this one)

```
List Type
```

to be that large.

The idea is that you can do all type-building operations at every level. Each time you use types from one level as values, the types of *those* structures live one level up.

Comment: `Type -> Type : Type`

Comment: I'm not sure that Idris reveals too much info about `Type` levels to the programmer. The `Type : Type 1` is probably just because `Type : Type` is a contradiction.

Comment: `Type -> Type` is indeed in `Type 1`, but it's also in `Type` (as Ramon noted). The same is true for `Nat -> Type` and `List Type`.

Comment: I'd check for myself, but "cabal install idris" threatens to break packages that I need for mission-critical software. I think there are two separate questions: what level does a type belong at? and how much level information does Idris display?

Comment: All Idris does is build a graph of constraints and check there are no cycles. The "Type : Type 1" thing is a display hack because people kept reporting that it was an inconsistency and I got bored of explaining it...

Comment: @Edwin: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks!